# where to place applicationcontext.xml file in a jar (spring project)

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I have created a spring project. I need to create a jar file of this project. I can able to create a jar file but applicationcontext.xml is placed outside when i open the jar. but where i need to exactly place the applicationcontext.xml in the jar, so that it gets loaded and I can use the spring bean inside the jar.

How to specify in pom.xml, that applicationcontext.xml should be placed inside the META-INF folder?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  I see you have asked a number of questions and have gotten some helpful answers.  Please remember to upvote and check answers which are helpful.  Members will be more eager to help when you give back to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your applicationcontext.xml file under the src/main/resources/META-INF folder in your maven project.

Answer (score 0):

I put it here -

src/main/resources/

and it worked